# Are WiFi Max Solutions worth considering

Tags: wifi, internet

We are looking at ways to help cut our costs and our T1 contract is up.  We have run across a local company that offers a 2mbit WiFi Max solution that is considerably cheaper than a T1.  They have a pretty standard SLA and references are all positive.  But I can't help but think that the references are all hand selected for the positive comments.

- Are wireless options worth considering over traditional T1 services?
- Anyone have any good or bad experiences with them?
- Any compelling arguments in favor or against these type of services?

We currently run our email, web, and ftp sites locally via our T1.

Comment: i think you refer to wimax rather then wifi

Comment: Yes you are correct.  Although I believe that this provider is not wimax but is some other licensed wireless spectrum like you mentioned in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

i'm using in couple of locations internet connections that come over fiber and some that come over wireless [ licensed spectrum, but not wimax ]. there are more issues with wireless... but it does work, and in many cases is much cheaper [ for the operator ] to provision.

problems that you might face with wireless links:

- some of connections i'm using tend to reboot during strong thunderstorm
- some of them deteriorated during high rains [ moist in the antenna interconnectors? ]

but as long as operator is responsible and provides reasonable hardware + will fix problems that might occur in short time - i do not see much problems.

still.. i think your ftp/www/mail servers would feel much better in some collocation facility with fast [ 2Mbit/s is not anywhere near fast nowadays ] internet connection, proper air conditioning and redundant power supply.

Answer (score 1):

I have yet to deploy a good WiMax solution.  We've tried Covad Wireless in LA and Sling Broadband in Miami and had issues with both.  I can't say they were related to WiMax specifically, but we have other microwave broadband deployments in the Chicagoland area that have zero issues.  I would recommend getting testimonials from customers on their network that are close to your physical location so you can get a sense of their service and support from people that are actually using it.

Comment: I have a few references from companies in my area who are using the tower that we would be relaying from.  So far no complaints....they were even up through the ice storm we had this past winter.