# Fixed wireless Internet connections vs. T1 vs. DSL

Tags: wifi, internet

I run a small business in Mountain View CA, and (as surprising as it sounds) I cannot get traditional high-speed Internet providers (e.g. Comcast, AT&T, Verizon, etc) to install DSL in my office because they do not service my business park.  My only other options for Internet are fixed wireless (at a 1 Mbps up/down) and a T-1 line.  Needless to say, a T-1 is out of my price range.  Does anyone have experience with fixed wireless Internet?  Would you recommend it or not?  What are some things to watch out for when contemplating whether or not to install fixed wireless?  Anything helps.  thx!

Comment: A while ago I asked a similar question.  http://serverfault.com/questions/26117/are-wifi-max-solutions-worth-considering

Answer (score 1):

I use Covad wireless at my own office as well as with many clients. It's great. We pay the same as a T1 and get much more bandwidth. It's totally reliable. There's a great SLA. It has gone down a couple of times, but support has always been amazing. We've never been down for more than an hour. There's more downtime than a traditional T1, but we've experienced less average downtime than any of our clients with DSL or cable.

Needless to say, I highly recommend it.

As for what to look out for, I don't know about anybody else, but Covad will take care of all of the details. If there's obstructions or other problems that would block the connection, they'll cancel the order without any liability. I've never had that happen, but it's comforting to know that there's nothing to lose in the worst case scenario